# Adding Master Page to dynamically created UI.Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I have page created dynamically

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Load(string path, string options)
{
    try
    {
        using (Page dynamicPage = new Page())
        {
            HtmlHead dynamicHead = new HtmlHead();

            // dynamicPage.PreInit += new EventHandler(InitPage);

            dynamicPage.Controls.Add(dynamicHead);
            HtmlForm dynamicForm = new HtmlForm();
            dynamicPage.Controls.Add(dynamicForm);

            ScriptManager dynamicScript = new ScriptManager();
            dynamicForm.Controls.Add(dynamicScript);

            UserControl userControl = (UserControl)dynamicPage.LoadControl(dynamicPage.ResolveUrl(path));

            //var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            // var data = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(options);
            // Dictionary<String, String> dict = (data as object[]).ToDictionary(key => (key as object[])[0].ToString(), val => (val as object[])[1].ToString());
            var jOptions = JObject.Parse(options);
            // foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> property in dict)
            {
                // PropertyInfo prop = userControl.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty(property.Key);
                // prop.SetValue(userControl, property.Value, null);

            }
            var gameId = jOptions["gameId"];
            ((IPickVsTrend)userControl).Init(long.Parse(gameId.ToString()), new PickCardService(new PickCardRepository()));
            ((IPickVsTrend)userControl).LoadTab(new FiltersModel { Date = DateTime.Now });


            //TextWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            //HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
            //userControl.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
            //string html = stringWriter.ToString();
            //return html;
            //error - wants to be inside a form tag with runat=server 

            dynamicForm.Controls.Add(userControl);

            using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                dynamicPage.Controls.Add(dynamicForm);
                HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(dynamicPage, writer, false);

                return writer.ToString();//.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Global.log.Error(String.Format("Error: AdminServices.cs: GetUserControl: :{0}:{1}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException));
        return ex.Message;
    }


}
```

but when I try to attach MasterPageFile property (even on PreInit handler) it throws exception at CombineVirtualPaths with object reference not set to instance of an object, what could be the case? this is being created through a web-method which is invoked from ajax call.
It seems that  dynamicPage.AppRelativeVirtualPath needs to be specified manually because it does not know where it is located physically, but now I have different error:

> System.Web.HttpException: 'Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.'

The problem narrows down to how to determine where to add new control in page, shall we use htmlWriter or is there any other option? also it seems that styles does no t apply correctly after dynamic load.